# Updating a table with 4 million rows of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have been asked to provide an update script to update the value of a column. Currently, the table stores 4 millions of records. The update logic is quite simple, just need to set the value of each record in that column to be an empty string. e.g.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column = '',
```

On one of our testing environment, it took more than 4 hours to execute this script and it is not even finished.

One thing to note is that, our product environment needs to be online during the script execution time, which means we allow user continue to write into the table at the same time.

I do consider dropping the column and re-adding it back with a default value. But that's gonna break the our prod environment for sure.

Is there any performance improvement I can apply in this case to reduce the execution time down to an hour ? e.g like updating the record in batches of 5000 ?

Comment: If you want to change the value of *every* row in the table of a single column, perhaps it would be quicker to `DROP` the column, and the readd it with a `DEFAULT` value (and define `WITH VALUES`). Then, if needed, `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT` afterwards. This, however, assumes no existing related constraints.

Comment: `UPDATE [DB_SCHEMA].[DB_TABLE].[COLUMN_NAME]` is somewhat confusing too; do you *really* have a database called `DB_SCHEMA`, a *schema* called `DB_TABLE` and a *table* called `COLUMN_NAME`?

Comment: Dropping the column and re-adding it with a default should certainly be quicker if you are on Enterprise Edition as both can be done as metadata only operations with no update to the data rows needed at all

Comment: Either your database is hosted on a smartwatch, which is unlikely, or the table has a `for update` trigger, which is, how shall I put this, not very well written.

Comment: Even on Express and Standard I've seen it be (significantly) quicker, in truth, @MartinSmith . I don't doubt, however, that Enterprise has some extra features that could make it "faster" still.

Comment: This was EE only when first released. Not sure if that has changed since. https://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/

Comment: @Larnu sorry that I didn't put enough information in the question. I can't just drop the column and re-add it back as it will break the prod env. Also the DB_SCHEMA].[DB_TABLE].[COLUMN_NAME] is just an example, not the real database and table name.

Comment: I know it's an example, but my point is that it's confusing when you have a database called "schema" a *schema* called "table" and a *table* called "column".

Comment: Why would, out of interest, dropping the column and re-adding it break the environment? Can you expand on how it would break it? *Presumably* you aren't relying on the ordinal positions of columns, no?

Comment: From my understanding, becoz we need to keep the prod env alive during this process (either executing script or dropping and re-adding column), and the client can send the request via our application to write data into table/column anytime. If we got unlucky and the request happens after we dropping the table, it kinda makes the application unusable. We tried to convince client to take down the server but the application is clinical/medical related, which it involves potential risk for the patient. Thats why it has to keep alive.

Comment: Did some experimenting, for what it's worth, @MartinSmith . Certainly on an Enterprise/Developer instance, yes, dropping and re-adding the column is *significantly* faster. On Standard/Express I still saw an improvement, but where on EE it would be a few ms at most to add the column, it was about half the time of an `UPDATE` in Express/Standard to add it; so looks to still be an EE feature (at least in 2017).

Comment: @FrancisZhu why are you talking about dropping the table? No one has suggested that? Also what edition of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @MartinSmith, thats for replying Larnu's question why dropping the column and re-adding it break the environment. We are using the AWS RDS, sql server 2017 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Follows a example, one way what the update could be done by range.

```
DECLARE @MaxKey as bigint;
DECLARE @RangeStart as bigint;
DECLARE @RangeEnd as bigint;
DECLARE @pass as int
DECLARE @stop as bit

--max key from your table
select  @MaxKey = MAX(PrimaryKey) from dbo.MyTable 

--the range update
SET @pass = 5000;

--variables to set the criteria WHERE
SET @RangeStart = 0
SET @RangeEnd = @pass

--variable to stop the loop
SET @stop = 0

While @stop = 0
Begin

    SELECT @RangeStart, @RangeEnd

    --update the field in range variable @pass
    update dbo.MyTable set myfield = '' where PrimaryKey between @RangeStart and @RangeEnd

    --criteria to stop the loop
    if @MaxKey < @RangeEnd
        SET @stop = 1

    --incrise the range
    SET @RangeStart = @RangeStart + @pass;

    SET @RangeEnd = @RangeEnd + @pass;

End
```